# What, why!? Tricky JS code spread ... and [].concat

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

Was just going through the source code for Laravel Mix (webpack setup) to get some inspiration on setting up my own webpack when I came across this.

```
rules.push(...[].concat(newRules))
```

I can't figure out what the point of this is but I trust Taylor wouldn't include anything superfluous just for the sake of it.

Surely any of these are just as good?

```
rules.concat(newRules)
```

or

```
rules.push(...newRules)
```

or even a good old for-loop! But why concat to empty array before spreading the elements?

Much appreciated if anybody can enlighten me on this.

Comment: Seems like they want to make use of the [`Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable), not just the iteration protocol.

Comment: Maybe `rules.push(...Array.from(newRules))` is slightly more understandable. Or `rules = rules.concat(newRules);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only speculate as I didn't author the code but I imagine the intention is to add `newRules` to `rules` where `newRules` could be any type (not just an array). [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) will create a new array while we want the original array mutated. [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates the array but how do you handle the case where `newRules` is an array? You can't just push `newRules` into `rules` because it'll be an array inside an array and you can't spread `newRules` because not everything is an iterable. `[].concat(newRules)` will add all of `newRules` to an array which essentially 'converts' non-arrays into an array and spreading that array inside push will add those items to `rules`.

Check out the test cases below and click <kbd>Run snippet</kbd> to see it in action:

```js
const PASSED = '✅ PASSED';
const FAILED = '❌ FAILED';

(() => {
  console.log('`rules.concat(newRules)`');
  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = [4, 5, 6];
    rules.concat(newRules);
    console.log('where `newRules` is an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();

  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = 4;
    rules.concat(newRules);
    console.log('where `newRules` is not an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();
  console.log('');
})();

(() => {
  console.log('');
  console.log('`rules.push(newRules)`');
  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = [4, 5, 6];
    rules.push(newRules);
    console.log('where `newRules` is an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();

  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = 4;
    rules.push(newRules);
    console.log('where `newRules` is not an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();
  console.log('');
})();

(() => {
  console.log('');
  console.log('`rules.push(...[].concat(newRules))`');
  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = [4, 5, 6];
    rules.push(...[].concat(newRules));
    console.log('where `newRules` is an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();

  (() => {
    const expectation = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const rules = [1, 2, 3];
    const newRules = 4;
    rules.push(...[].concat(newRules));
    console.log('where `newRules` is not an array:', _.isEqual(expectation, rules) ? PASSED : FAILED);
  })();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much for breaking it down and for the detailed example. I still don't get how `[].concat(newRules)` will convert `newRules` into an array (since concat works with plain single elements too) but it makes sense to mutate the original array and still be able to accept an array!

Comment: If you concat two arrays you'll get one array with the two arrays joined together. If you concat a non array with an array you'll get one array with the non array added to the end. See these two examples which both produce `[1, 2, 3]`: `[1, 2].concat(3)` and `[1, 2].concat([3])`.